# Как открыть форму с пониженными правами (не админа), если приложение запущено под админом?

Tags: c#, winforms, manifest, uac

Приложение стартует с правами админа. Почему? Потому что оно стартует/останавливает службу, меняет настройки старта службы... В общем и в этом приложении есть Drag&Drop, который конечно же не доступен.

Вопрос мой звучит так... Можно ли как то с помощью манифест файла сделать так, чтобы отдельная форма запускалась как отдельный процесс с пониженными правами, дабы я могу использовтаь dra&drop?

Есть вариант запускать приложение  под обычными правами, но тогда надо будет писать command line для старта и остановки службы, конфигурирования... и это все как-то не особо радует. Есть ли какеи варианты у меня? Очень бы хотелось чтобы под правами админа работал DragDrop. Спасибо.

Comment: Привелегии, насколько мне известно, работают на уровне процессов. То есть если нужно окно с пониженными правами, значит процесс, в котором будет это окно, надо с этими правами запускать. То есть понижение подчиняется тем же условиям, что и повышение.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему у вас drag&drop под админом не работает, но вы всегда средствами программы можете запустить exe от другого пользователя, а самого пользователя автоматически создать с настройкой чтобы его не было в списке пользователей при логине. Манифест тут кажется ничем не поможет. Но лучше конечно внешний контроллер для управления службой в виде параллельно запущенной службы.